# Non-multiplicative Euler-Poincaré Characteristics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, euler-characteristics

Are there known examples of a non-multiplicative Euler-Poincaré characteristic on varieties?

Let $\mathbf{Var}/k$ be the category of varieties over a filed $k$, i.e. the category of reduced separated schemes of finite type over $k$, and let $\mathop{\mathrm{K}}_0(\mathbf{Var}/k)$ be its Grothendieck ring.

A (generalised) Euler-Poincaré characteristic is a group homomorphism from $\mathop{\mathrm{K}}_0(\mathbf{Var}/k)$. All examples of Euler-Poincaré characteristics that I am aware of happen to be multiplicative, i.e. each of them is given by a ring homomorphism $ \mathop{\mathrm{K}}_0(\mathbf{Var}/k) \to R$, for some ring $R$. Ramachandran and Tabuada's [Exponentiation of Motivic Measures](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1795v1) provides examples of multiplicative Euler-Poincaré characteristics, e.g. counting rational point over a finite field, the Hodge characteristic, the Poincaré characteristic, the Larsen-Lunts measure, the Albanese measure, and the Gillet-Soulé measure.

<strike>I am mainly interested in 'non-artificial' characteristics (ones that people actually use); Nevertheless, I would like to know if any 'artificial' or 'non-artificial' example is known.</strike>

**Edit:**
I would like to know an example of non-multiplicative characteristic that is not arising from a multiplicative one.

**Edit 2:** Apparently, I am only interested in 'non-artificial' non-multiplicative characteristics that people actually use, did not arise by forgetting some of the data a multiplicative characteristic give, or by composing with an arbitrary group homomorphism.

Comment: Just compose any of the characteristics you know with an abelian group homomorphism. For example, you can take your favorite Hodge number, or your favorite linear combination of Hodge numbers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks, yea sure, my formulation for the question was rather silly. What is relevant to me is characteristics that are not coming from multiplicative ones.

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense as edited. By “arising from a multiplicative one”, I understand that an additive invariant $\alpha$ is induced by a multiplicative invariant $\chi$ composed with a morphism of abelian groups. But every additive invariant has this form, with $\chi$ the identity...